# How to escape "!" and "&" in docker's environment varibles

Tags: shell, escape-characters, escaping, docker

I have a docker container I want to run and hand it over some passwords. One with an exclamation mark `!` and the other one with an ampersand `&`. So I want to run this:

```
docker run -i -t --rm \
-e "LDAP_FILTER=(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)" \
-e "LDAP_PASS=Secret!Password" \
user-prefix/container-name
```

That does not work. `&` gets replaced to `{LDAP_FILTER}` and the `!` get truncated. I'm pretty sure I have to escape these. But `\!` and `\&` didn't work out.

Comment: Have you tried with single quotes? Since you don't have any variables to interpolate, you can get away with single quotes here.

Comment: A blind shot: If the `-e` parameter gets executed by another shell instance, you might have to escape twice, so try `\\\&` and `\\\!`.

Comment: @mpy the \\\ trick did it for me, thats the best!

Answer (score 28):

I found a solution:

- Using single-quotes instead of double-quotes
- Escape the ampersand `&` to `\&`
- Not escaping the exclamation mark `!`

so this works:

```
docker run -i -t --rm \
-e 'LDAP_FILTER=(\&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)' \
-e 'LDAP_PASS=Secret!Password' \
user-prefix/container-name
```

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot use single-quotes for the entire string for some reason (e.g. variable expansion), this is probably the best solution: [In bash, how do I escape an exclamation mark?](https://superuser.com/a/301330/1129381)

In summary: Use `"'!'"` around the exclamation mark:

```bsh
echo "hello there"'!'" and goodbye"
```