# What is echo doing?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, echo

Recently, I noticed that echos in which I include lots of "!" result in weird stuff. For example: `echo !!` gives me:

```
echo rm -r * 1000
rm -r * 1000
```

(`rm -r *` was the last command I executed before typing it). Why is this happening, and is there a way to disable it?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/133782/432690

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ran into `shell expansion` - the shell will parse your command and replace a special wildcards with other information. Try `echo '!!'` (single quotes) to understand what shell expansion and quoting can do.

You can read more about shell expansion in the `man` page for `bash`. Note the sections for [history expansion](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#HISTORY_EXPANSION), which discusses `event designators` like `!!`, and [expansion](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION), which discusses other forms of shell expansion. The section on [quoting](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#QUOTING) explains the behavior of bash's quoting mechanisms and the difference between how single and double quoted strings are evaluated.